# How to save a Bitmap image to a png and/or pdf file

Tags: swift, graphics, png, bitmapimage

I am trying to figure out how to create bitmaps using Swift and Cocoa on mac OS
I found this example on the web.

```
// LibPNG example
// A.Greensted
// http://www.labbookpages.co.uk
```

Using libpng and a bridging header I converted this example to Swift. I don't want to normally use libpng since it does not appear to be one of the standard Apple supplied frameworks.  I am trying to learn how to use Core Graphics and Cocoa. (I am trying to avoid objective C and just use Swift)

I wrote the following code using the above example which runs in a playground.  In the margin I get a nice mandelbrot image.  I can't figure out how to turn this into a pdf and/or png and how to save it to a file.  It seems like this should be easy.  Pointers on how to do this would be appreciated; or a pointer to a previous answer. Apple changes their API so frequently many of the answers are stale.

If you run my example place the functions (createMandelbrot, setRGB, makeRGBImage) in a separate file in the sources directory if you run this in a playground.  If the mandelbrot function is in the main playground window the iteration takes forever.

```
import Cocoa
let h = 500
let w = 500
let mandelbrot = createMandelbrot(width: w, height: h, xS:  -0.802, yS: -0.177, rad: 0.011, maxIteration: 110)
let context = makeRGBImage(width: w, height: h, buffer: mandelbrot)
let image = NSImage(cgImage: context.makeImage()!, size: NSSize(width: w, height: h))
```

Below in files in Sources Directory.

```
import Foundation
public func createMandelbrot(width: Int, height: Int, xS: Double, yS:  Double, rad: Double, maxIteration:  Int) -> [Double] {
var buffer = Array<Double>(repeating: 0.0, count: width * height)
var minMu = Double(maxIteration)
var maxMu = 0.0
for yPos in 0..<height {
    let yP: Double = (yS-rad) + (2.0 * rad/Double(height)) * Double(yPos);

    for xPos in 0..<width {
        let xP: Double = (xS - rad) + (2.0 * rad/Double(width)) * Double(xPos)

        var iteration:Int = 0
        var x = 0.0
        var y = 0.0
        while x * x + y * y <= 4 && iteration < maxIteration {
            let tmp = x * x - y * y + xP
            y = 2 * x * y + yP
            x = tmp;
            iteration += 1
        }
        if iteration < maxIteration {
            let modZ = sqrt(x * x + y * y)
            let mu = Double(iteration) - (log(log(modZ))) / log(2.0)
            if mu > maxMu {
                maxMu = mu
            }
            if mu < minMu {
                minMu = mu
            }
            buffer[yPos * width + xPos] = mu
        }
        else {
            buffer[yPos * width + xPos] = 0
        }
    }
}
// Scale buffer values between 0 and 1
var count = width * height;
while count > 0 {
    count -= 1
    buffer[count] = (buffer[count] - minMu) / (maxMu - minMu)
}
return buffer
}



import Cocoa
func setRGB(ptr: inout [UInt8], val: Double)
{
var v = Int(val * 767)
if (v < 0) {
    v = 0
} else if (v > 767){
    v = 767
}
let offset: Int = v % 256

if (v<256) {
    ptr[0] = 0; ptr[1] = 0; ptr[2] = UInt8(offset)
}
else if (v<512) {
    ptr[0] = 0; ptr[1] = UInt8(offset); ptr[2] = 255 - UInt8(offset)
}
else {
    ptr[0] = UInt8(offset); ptr[1] = 255 - UInt8(offset); ptr[2] = 0
}
ptr[3] = 255
}


public func makeRGBImage(width: Int, height: Int, buffer: [Double]) -> CGContext
{
let bitmapInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4 * width, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)
var pix: [UInt8] = [0,0,0,0]
let dta = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(mutating: context?.data?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self))!
// Write image data
for y in 0..<height {
    let jmp = 4 * width * y
    for x in 0..<width {
        let indxBuf = y * width + x
        setRGB(ptr: &pix, val: buffer[indxBuf])
        let indxPix = 4 * x + jmp
        dta[indxPix] = pix[0]   // red
        dta[indxPix+1] = pix[1] // green
        dta[indxPix+2] = pix[2] // blue
        dta[indxPix+3] = pix[3] // alpha
    }
}
return context!
}
```

Comment: Is your question basically how to write your `NSImage` as a PNG image file?

Comment: I should be able to save it as any image format but png is probably best for this type image.

Comment: note: not a Cocoa answer, but I have written a pure Swift library that does exactly this, writing a pixel buffer to a PNG file — [`MaxPNG`](https://github.com/kelvin13/maxpng)

Answer (score 2):

Your code makes a good start of drawing into a graphics context.  The next step would likely be to get a CGImage from the context (`CGBitmapContextCreateImage`).  From there you could create an data consumer that puts information into a file (`CGDataConsumer(url: ___)`), then create an image destination (`CGImageDestinationCreateWithDataConsumer`) with a type of `kUTTypePNG` and add the image to the destination (`CGImageDestinationAddImage`)

Be sure you call `CGImageDestinationFinalize`

Comment: This is what I mean by things getting stale.  In Swift using CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context) results in an error.  The correct usage seems to be something like let image = context.makeImage() which I use in my code.  I will explore you other suggestions but what I want is something like context.writeToFile(file: String, as: CGContex,png).  Don't know why they need all this other nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestions of Scott Thompson I wrote the following in the main playground page.  It would produce a png file that opened but was just a gray box with no mandelbrot.  PDF failed to produce a file that would open.

```
import Cocoa
let h = 500
let w = 500
let mandelbrot = createMandelbrot(width: w, height: h, xS:  -0.802, yS: -0.177, rad: 0.011, maxIteration: 110)
let context = makeRGBImage(width: w, height: h, buffer: mandelbrot)
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/judd/local/mandelbrot.png")
let dc = CGDataConsumer(url: url as CFURL)
let dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithDataConsumer(dc!, kUTTypePNG, 1, nil)
CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest!, context.makeImage()!, nil)
CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest!)
```

I then used the exact same code except instead of a playground I started a new project and placed the playground code in main.  Everything worked fine.  I then went back to the playground environment and made a new file in Sources where I placed a file with the following functions.

```
import Cocoa
public func writeToPNG(context: CGContext) {
   let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/judd/local/mandelbrot.png")
    let dc = CGDataConsumer(url: url as CFURL)
    let dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithDataConsumer(dc!, kUTTypePNG, 1, nil)
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest!, context.makeImage()!, nil)
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest!)
}
public func writeToPDF(context: CGContext) {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/judd/local/mandelbrot.pdf")
    let dc = CGDataConsumer(url: url as CFURL)
    let dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithDataConsumer(dc!, kUTTypePDF, 1, nil)
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest!, context.makeImage()!, nil)
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest!)
}
```

My main playground page now looks like

```
import Cocoa
let h = 500
let w = 500
let mandelbrot = createMandelbrot(width: w, height: h, xS:  -0.802, yS: -0.177, rad: 0.011, maxIteration: 110)
let context = makeRGBImage(width: w, height: h, buffer: mandelbrot)
writeToPNG(context: context)
writeToPDF(context: context)
```

This worked fine and I got a proper png and pdf image in my files.  There seem to be a problems with doing stuff from a main playground page causing some confusion.